# Java generic type for objects

Tags: java, android

In Objective-C we have a generic type for objects called "id".

```
id someObject = someValue;
if([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *string = someObject;
}
```

I want to know if there's something like that in Java.

```
id someObject = someValue;
if(someObject instanceof String) {
    String string = someObject;
}
```

Comment: The `Object` class is the root of the class hierarchy in Java.

Comment: You can do this, but there's generally a better way. Generics are preferable to casting these days. Could you give us some more context?

Comment: The approach for using "Object" worked fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Matt, do you know where I can learn about Generics? Article, tutorial etc... Thanks.

Comment: You can start from the source :)  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you were very close to the answer yourself:

```
// obtain your object from somewhere
Object someObject = obtainObjectInstance();

// if it's a string...
if(someObject instanceof String) {
    // cast and assign to some variable
    String string = (String)someObject;
}
```

As a side note, all object instances contain information about the object's class: `someObject.getClass()`

Comment: I'm glad to have helped, but please note that as Matt pointed out, `instanceof` is a kind of a last resort. Usually there's a more elegant way of approaching the "problem" such as generics, abstractions or other OOP concepts

Comment: Thanks, Grove. If you know any tutorial about this, I will appreciate.

Comment: Yes, there's usually a more elegant solution involving instanceof, but that's not what the question asked.